# ConnectorConnector.php line no :55 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql1.alwaysdata.com:3306' (2)

Tags: ubuntu

I got solution for this problem.

use 127.0.0.1 insted of localhost in **.env** file or whwre you used localhost..

Answer (score 0):

use 127.0.0.1 insted of localhost in .env file or where you used localhost.. in laravel .env file which is located on the bottom of project.